# Bare bones API server vs Complete web server for API handling

Tags: api, sockets, nginx, lua

I was recently developing a socket based system using Lua which was quickly turning into a web server , I wrote a small API which is tightly coupled with the socket logic and I found myself with everything that I needed to have a full fledged API service without worrying about everything else that a conventional web server is usually bundled with. Since I was using OpenID I discovered I don't need a cookie parser in the server logic and since I was only serving JSON data , I skipped implementing file management utilities which by the way are almost 30% of any decent server design.

I think what I developed ended up being a small framework that serves my JSON API , I stress tested the code and I could do up to 10K connection simultaneously since I was am asynchronous sockets and the load on the development computer was alright by me.

Is it advisable to design this way? , I mean I cannot get any good examples from companies that do this from a quick google search but I am sure there are those who do this. I am impressed by the simplicity that I got and the quick design time, most of the time I have to study complex web server internal things in order to accomplish such a task but having written everything incrementally , I seriously discovered that the learning curve is much shorter.

My entire code base is reasonably small excluding the Lua runtime and I can run a twitter like micro blogging service with exemplary error handling via the API. I am now designing the API front-end which will run on a full fledged web server (NGINX) ... I would really like to know if Implementing the API back-end on a dedicated custom stack is the best way to go or maybe I am setting myself up for some pretty crazy surprises in the long run.